# Setting discoverable mode for bluetooth to always on seam to fail

Tags: android, bluetooth, discoverability

I am trying to set the `bluetooth discoverable` mode to always on in `Android 4.0`. This should be possible with 4.0, with the command:

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
enableBtIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
```

After executing this I get a dialog that asks if it is OK to start bluetooth with discoverybility always on. If I press yes the bluetooth setting will show the time 0:00 and it will NOT countdown. So far it looks fine, but after 2 min the bluetooth will change to unvisible mode again (if the previous setting was 2 min). Only if the previous setting was always on (set by manually going into the bluetooth settings) the Intent will work.

Does anyone know more about this? Is this a bug or is it how it is supposed to be? Should it not be possible to change the setting to always on by code?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed as per the API docs . [See this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION)

It defaults to 120 seconds and max is 300 seconds

Comment: Thanks, it is probably a problem with my device in that case.