# BroadcastReceiver never called

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to scan for bluetooth devices, but the register is never called:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


          ArrayList<String> arr_devices = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> arr_in_range = new ArrayList<String>();
          Button btn_devices;
          BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
          IntentFilter filter;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            btn_devices = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
            btn_devices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    if (bluetooth != null)
                    {
                        if (bluetooth.isEnabled())
                        {
                            //this is called
                            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                            Log.i("State", bluetoothAdapter.getState() + ""); //12 (STATE_ON)
                            Log.i("Discovery", bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering() + "");  //FALSE

                            filter = new IntentFilter();
                            filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
                            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

                           registerReceiver(myreceiver, filter);
                           //this is where the program stops. No more actions are performed
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterReceiver(myreceiver);
        }


        final BroadcastReceiver myreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //I placed a Log statement here but it doesn't appear in the logcat
           String action = intent.getAction();

           if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
           }
           else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
           }

           if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
           {
               BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
               Log.i("device", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
           }

         }};

    }
```

Bluetooth is enabled. What am I missing?

Comment: Use Log.v statements to ensure that bluetooth isn't null, and bluetooth is showing up as enabled on the device. Also, print out the value of the startDiscovery.

Comment: I think you need to put the myreceiver declaration inside of onCreate(). Right now you are instantiating that outside of the lifecycle methods but still in the Activity. I think it will be null when you register it so it will seem like you aren't getting callbacks.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: I am using log statements, but removed them to provide a transparent code.

Comment: Where does it stop then? Can you edit your code with comments to show where it stopped?

Comment: Hm. Right after calling startDiscovery() I logged out the value of bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering() which is false. Any ideas? I added some comments to the code

Comment: What was the return on `bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()`?

Comment: Also, do a `bluetoothAdapter.getState()`, and verify that it is STATE_ON (12/0x0c)

Comment: It returns 12, see code. What do you mean by return on `bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your broadcast receiver before

```
 bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Cause you startDiscovery and after you listen broadcastListener.

Comment: sometimes bluetooth stops working. it doesn't force close, but the value of bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering() returns false. No matter if I restart the app, I need to turn off and on bluetooth to make it work again. Any ideas?

Comment: startDiscovery launch device to search new BT devices but when it have done isDiscovering return false you have to call again startDiscovery. Look doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Comment: I am familiar with this. But I keep pressing btn_devices the value returns false. If you take another look at the code you'll see the startDiscovery() method is inside the btn_devices onClickListener, so the discovery should be started again..

Comment: Sorry maybe take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837386/setting-discoverable-mode-for-bluetooth-to-always-on-seam-to-fail

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have two bluetooth adapters set up? The system might be getting confused with both of them, you should only need one. I recommend you remove the line listed below, and change all references from bluetooth to bluetoothAdapter.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

I suspect what is happening is that this is returning null, as you already have a copy of the receiver, or something similar to that.

Also, make sure you have added the permissions to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

All of that failing, you might try rebooting your phone. At least on my phone, bluetooth gets mucked up sometimes.

Comment: I accidentally left the other bluetoothAdapter. I did what you said, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Okay, make sure you added the permission to the manifest as well, as I just edited my answer.

Comment: BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions are added, the app would force close without them.